# Nobody likes fillers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Let's get rid of [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) tag? It's not like there are "anime filler specialists" going around answering those.

Comment: I strongly concur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no longer any questions that have the [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) tag.

I just synonymized [filler](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filler) and [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) to [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production).

Comment: Are you sure? I still see http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/194/1908, http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4318/1908, http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5352/1908, http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19932/1908, http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19929/1908 all with [tag:fillers], though maybe that's just caching.

Comment: synonymized filler and fillers to anime-production as most of it seemed appropriate (in the case that filler was the only tag). It should be updated by now.

Comment: Ah, it sure is now. Hooray!